# Where can I get Android Mediaframeworktest test media files?

Tags: android

Does anybody have the Android mediaframeworktest test media files?

Answer (score 0):

Try to google it with " + git + android". It will return results with the paths and links to the file(s) in git(android repository).

You can view all android source files there and also see diff of files and changes made.

Best of Luck!!

Comment: You can also take a look at the CTS test package for the required test files

Answer (score 0):

Go to [download](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html) section on AOSP and get CTS Media Files ([download zip](http://dl.google.com/dl/android/cts/android-cts-media-1.0.zip)).